# How to use a function within useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React Sortable HOC to move items around. My initial state is an empty array and I need to update the state with a function from React Sortable.

This is the original snippet from React Sortable HOC

```
onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
    this.setState(({items}) => ({
      items: arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex),
    }));
  };
```

My state and function look like this

```
const [colors, setColors] = useState([])

function onSortEnd({ oldIndex, newIndex }) {
  setColors([...colors, ({ colors }) => ({
     colors: arrayMove(colors, oldIndex, newIndex)
  })]);
};
```

What ends up happening is no errors, but more colors get added when I attempt to arrange any existing color.

Comment: What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: In first example your state is object wheras in second you're trying to set as array ? is it what you're trying or a typo here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the requirement mentioned, I think you don't need the callback format for `setState` and you can simply do

```js
const [colors, setColors] = useState([])

function onSortEnd({ oldIndex, newIndex }) {
  const newColors = arrayMove(colors, oldIndex, newIndex);
  setColors(newColors);
};
```

Comment: It's recommend to pass a function to the setters returned from useState, that way you always have the latest value

Comment: When your new values is dependent on the previous state then it's recommended otherwise it's not.

Comment: You need to explain what you have changed and why. `Try this` is not a helpful statement. And even if the answer is correct, one needs to seek the changes.

Comment: Sure, Thanks for the suggestion. I will make sure to add the complete details going forward.

Comment: For anyone who is getting `Cannot read property 'collection' of null` try using the functional approach. Pulled a lot of my hair out over this one. 

`setColors(newColors => arrayMove(newColors, oldIndex, newIndex));`

Answer (score 1):

Need to return a list instead of object in your `setColors()`.

This should work:

```
const [colors, setColors] = useState([]) // a list not an object

function onSortEnd({ oldIndex, newIndex }) {
  setColors(( colors ) => (
    arrayMove(colors, oldIndex, newIndex)  // return list
  ));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're updating the `colors` state with a new array object that contains existing colors spread into that array (ie `[...colors,`), along with the newly moved items returned from `arrayMove()`:

```
const [colors, setColors] = useState([])

function onSortEnd({ oldIndex, newIndex }) {

  /* 
  Look like a problem:
  Colors state updated to include existing ...colors, and result of function 
  */
  setColors([...colors, ({ colors }) => ({
     colors: arrayMove(colors, oldIndex, newIndex)
  })]);
};
```

My understanding is that to replicate the behavior of your "non-hook" component, you'll want to update your state's shape to `{ colors : [] }`, remove the spread operator, and return the `{ colors : [..] }` object directly to maintain a consistent state shape:

```
const [colors, setColors] = useState({ colors : [] })

function onSortEnd({ oldIndex, newIndex }) {

  /* 
  Pass current nested colors state array to arrayMove() and return
  resulting colors as nested state array
  */
  setColors(({ colors }) => ({
     colors: arrayMove(colors, oldIndex, newIndex)
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> What ends up happening is no errors, but more colors get added when I
>   attempt to arrange any existing color.

```
setColors([...colors, ({ colors })
               |______________________ spreading previous values to new array
```

Because you're spreading the previous colors and then adding the values which are returned from `arrayMove` if you just wanted to shift the colors, you can do it this way

```
const [colors, setColors] = useState([])

function onSortEnd({ oldIndex, newIndex }) {
  setColors(() => arrayMove(colors, oldIndex, newIndex));
};
```

Comment: Thank you @CodeManiac, but it gave me 'array is undefined'. I got it to work with the answer below. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Dave.Q see the updated one, anyways happy to help :)